# How to change hyperlink target of frame titles in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

The default behaviour is that clicking on frame titles takes you to the next slide. I would like to change that behaviour but I can't seem to workout how it is achieved when reading the Beamer source code.

How do you change the hyperlink target of frame titles in Beamer?

**Edit**

I was hardcoding hyperlinks into the titles as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\href{http://www.yahoo.com}{Yahoo}}
Blah
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}
Blah
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\href{http://www.bing.com}{Bing}}
Blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And it wasn't working. I thought my hyperlink behaviour was somehow being overwritten by Beamer but it turns out that it was just the PDF viewer misbehaving.

Comment: Can you please add to your question some minimal and complete document reproducing the mentioned behaviour? Hyperlinks usually take you to the right frame... so I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: How exactly would you like to change the hyperlink behaviour?

Comment: It is difficult understand what you are wondering because it's not true that you go in the next slide just clicking on the title. Try to click in another point of the frame: you will go to next slide.

Comment: The default behaviour is not broken, I would just like it to link somewhere else. Start of the section, for example...

Comment: If you want to point to the start of a section you can, for example, choose a theme that made use of the `navigation bar` then click on it. One example: the `Frankfurt` theme.

Comment: @DaleRoberts: A minimal example I create with a frame containing `\frametitle{Some title}` does not hyperlink to the next frame when I click on it. So, please include a small example the clearly illustrates your problem. It would ease the diagnosis and stop people from guessing and mostly likely provide the best opportunity for solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems that it was my PDF viewer misbehaving...